# Magento not showing orders but in html you can see the info

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I login and go to sales > orders > click an order, it shows the headers but not the content.

I when you view the html you can see the data.

Any ideas?

Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDuYx.jpg

What is even stranger is that there are 'display:none' tags in the html for those areas, if I remove them then it shows everything as it should.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb9si.jpg

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Are you receiving any JS errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code, and rendering process doesn't finish. Check both PHP log and JS console for errors